# If $f(xy)=xf(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, then $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

> Let $A$ be the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(xy)=xf(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. If $f\in A$ then show that  $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

***My attempt:***

Given $f(xy)=xf(y)$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. Since for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, $x+y\in \mathbb{R}$,

so  we have $$f((x+y)z)=(x+y)f(z)\quad \text{for all}\; x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}.$$
Now we choose $z=1$, $$f((x+y)1)=(x+y)f(1)\quad \text{for all}\;x,y\in \mathbb{R}.$$
$$\therefore f(x+y)=xf(1)+yf(1)=f(x)+f(y)\quad \text{for all}\;x,y\in \mathbb{R},$$ since $xf(y)=f(xy)$ and put $y=1$ gives $xf(1)=f(x)$.

Is my proof  correct? If it is, then I am looking for alternative proof.

Comment: Seems simpler to write $f(x)=f(x\times 1)=x\times f(1)$.

Comment: Yes. Did you mean $f(x+y)=f((x+y)\times1)=(x+y)f(1)=xf(1)+yf(1)=f(x)+f(y)$?

Comment: I'm just pointing out that $f(x)$ is of the form $f(x)=cx$ for a constant $c$.  Given that, then of course $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

Comment: How can you conclude that $f(x)=cx$ for a constant $c$?

Comment: $c=f(1)\,\,\,\,$

Comment: Yes, I got it..

Comment: Your proof is correct!

Answer (score 1):

Put $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+\phi(x+y)$.

Clearly $f(0)=0$ so you have $f(x)=f(x+0)=f(x)+f(0)+\phi(x+0)$ Thus
$$f(x)=f(x)+\phi(x)\space\text {for all } x\iff \phi(x)=0\space\text {for all } x$$ Thus $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$